Problem whit validating data HorizontalPodAutoscaler
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: error validating "": error validating data: [ValidationError(HorizontalPodAutoscaler.spec.metrics[0].resource): unknown field "targetAverageUtilization" in io.k8s.api.autoscaling.v2beta2.ResourceMetricSource, ValidationError(HorizontalPodAutoscaler.spec.metrics[0].resource): missing required field "target" in io.k8s.api.autoscaling.v2beta2.ResourceMetricSource]
my HorizontalPodAutoscaler:
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
......
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    kind: Deployment
    name: academy-backend-api
    apiVersion: apps/v1
  minReplicas: 2
  maxReplicas: 5
  metrics:
    - type: Resource
      resource:
        name: memory
        target:
          type: Utilization
          averageUtilization: 80
    - type: Resource
      resource:
        name: cpu
        target:
          type: Utilization
          averageUtilization: 60

and my values.yaml:
autoscaling:
  enabled: true
  minReplicas: 2
  maxReplicas: 4
  targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 80
  # targetMemoryUtilizationPercentage: 80

i tried to rewrite my values.yaml but nothing changed

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
